# Why does \alpha (outside of math mode) create a double quote?

Tags: typography, greek

I am not an experienced TeX user, so maybe this is obvious, but searching did not yield me anything.

I wanted to write a lowercase greek alpha, so I used the `\alpha` command, at first outside of math mode, and the text displayed `"⍺`. Why does it behave like that?

EDIT: there was no error thrown (as is the case if I write, e.g., `\to` outside of math mode)

Comment: `\alpha` is only legal in math mode. You get an error message and the output cannot be relied upon.

Comment: @egreg I surmised as much, however, in other cases, such as \to, the console throws an error and the document does not compile. in the case of \alpha, it prints it without a problem. my question is, why?

Comment: Do you use LuaTeX? It does not complain about the most math commands outside math mode.

Comment: The definition of `\alpha` is `\mathchar"010B` where the `"` indicates hexadecimal input, but maybe outside of math mode LuaTeX interprets this as a normal double quote or something - I can't reproduce it by the way, LuaLaTeX compiles without errors but the character is not shown at all (pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX both result in the `missing $ inserted` error).

Comment: @Marijn that is probably it. I am using TeXShop with TeXLive standard LaTeX, so behaviours might be different between implementations. But the hex explanation is probably correct, thanks for clearing that up!